# Convert String "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss Etc/GMT" to timestamp in UTC pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timestamp, utc

I have a pandas column of datetime-like string values like this exampe:

```py
exammple_value = "2022-06-24 16:57:33 Etc/GMT"
```

Expected output

```
Timestamp('2022-06-24 16:57:33+0000', tz='UTC')
```

Etc/GMT is the timezone, you can get it in python with:

```py
import pytz
list(filter(lambda x: 'GMT' in x, pytz.all_timezones))[0]

----
OUT: 
'Etc/GMT'
```

Comment: What is `Etc` in real data?

Comment: 'Etc/GMT' is the timezone https://pvlib-python.readthedocs.io/en/v0.3.0/timetimezones.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with `%Z` for parse timezones and for UTC use [`Timestamp.tz_convert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.tz_convert.html):

```
exammple_value = "2022-06-24 16:57:33 Etc/GMT"

print (pd.to_datetime(exammple_value, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z').tz_convert('UTC'))
2022-06-24 16:57:33+00:00
```

Another idea is remove timezones by split:

```
print (pd.to_datetime(exammple_value.rsplit(maxsplit=1)[0]).tz_localize('UTC'))
2022-06-24 16:57:33+00:00
```

Comment: thanks, ok so there is no panads recognition of the ETC/GMT directly, just cut it out and covert. thanks.

Comment: @Leo - Just added to answer.